# Fastest way to generate binomial coefficients

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures

I need to calculate combinations for a number.

What is the fastest way to calculate nCp where n>>p?

I need a fast way to generate binomial coefficients for an polynomial equation and I need to get the coefficient of all the terms and store it in an array.

> (a+b)^n = a^n + nC1 a^(n-1) * b + nC2 a^(n-2) * ............
>   +nC(n-1) a * b^(n-1) + b^n

What is the most efficient way to calculate nCp ??

Comment: I tried to calculate Combination using the traditional way, but as you may have guessed its very inefficient and takes a lot of time even for small polynomials

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: usually it means "n is much bigger than p".

Comment: @rao_555: what size numbers are `n` and `p`? And what kind of language? For example in languages which have fundamentally faster arithmetic on small numbers, it makes a difference to the answer whether it's even worth *trying* to compute the result in an `unsigned long long` (example taken from C) and avoid overflow by clever tricks, or whether the result is much bigger than that anyway, and so there's no point trying.

Comment: n and p can be both of order 10^10.

Comment: @rao_555 So you want to store a polynomial with order of 10^10 very large numbers?  Even a basic back of the envelope says that will not fit in memory on a personal computer.

Comment: @rao_555: well, if `n` is 10^10 and `p` is `n/2`, then nCp has approximately 45 billion decimal digits. Personally I would try to change the requirements at that point.

Comment: Sorry, 10 billion digits. Still.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You must have physics or engineering training.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want complete expansions for large values of n, FFT convolution might be the fastest way. In the case of a binomial expansion with equal coefficients (e.g. a series of fair coin tosses) and an even order (e.g. number of tosses) you can exploit symmetries thus:

**Theory**

Represent the results of two coin tosses (e.g. half the difference between the total number of heads and tails) with the expression A + A*cos(Pi*n/N). N is the number of samples in your buffer - a binomial expansion of even order O will have O+1 coefficients and require a buffer of N  >=  O/2 + 1 samples - n is the sample number being generated, and A is a scale factor that will usually be either 2 (for generating binomial coefficients) or 0.5 (for generating a binomial probability distribution).

Notice that, in frequency, this expression resembles the binomial distribution of those two coin tosses - there are three symmetrical spikes at positions corresponding to the number (heads-tails)/2. Since modelling the overall probability distribution of independent events requires convolving their distributions, we want to convolve our expression in the frequency domain, which is equivalent to multiplication in the time domain.

In other words, by raising our cosine expression for the result of two tosses to a power (e.g. to simulate 500 tosses, raise it to the power of 250 since it already represents a pair), we can arrange for the binomial distribution for a large number to appear in the frequency domain. Since this is all real and even, we can substitute the DCT-I for the DFT to improve efficiency.

**Algorithm**

1. decide on a buffer size, N, that is at least O/2 + 1 and can be conveniently DCTed
2. initialise it with the expression pow(A + A*cos(Pi*n/N),O/2)
3. apply the forward DCT-I
4. read out the coefficients from the buffer - the first number is the central peak where heads=tails, and subsequent entries correspond to symmetrical pairs successively further from the centre

**Accuracy**

There's a limit to how high O can be before accumulated floating-point rounding errors rob you of accurate integer values for the coefficients, but I'd guess the number is pretty high. Double-precision floating-point can represent 53-bit integers with complete accuracy, and I'm going to ignore the rounding loss involved in the use of pow() because the generating expression will take place in FP registers, giving us an extra 11 bits of mantissa to absorb the rounding error on Intel platforms. So assuming we use a 1024-point DCT-I implemented via the FFT, that means losing 10 bits' accuracy to rounding error during the transform and not much else, leaving us with ~43 bits of clean representation. I don't know what order of binomial expansion generates coefficients of that size, but I dare say it's big enough for your needs.

**Asymmetrical expansions**

If you want the asymmetrical expansions for unequal coefficients of a and b, you'll need to use a two-sided (complex) DFT and a complex pow() function. Generate the expression A*A*e^(-Pi*i*n/N) + A*B + B*B*e^(+Pi*i*n/N) [using the complex pow() function to raise it to the power of half the expansion order] and DFT it. What you have in the buffer is, again, the central point (but not the maximum if A and B are very different) at offset zero, and it is followed by the upper half of the distribution. The upper half of the buffer will contain the lower half of the distribution, corresponding to heads-minus-tails values that are negative.

Notice that the source data is Hermitian symmetrical (the second half of the input buffer is the complex conjugate of the first), so this algorithm is not optimal and can be performed using a complex-to-complex FFT of half the required size for optimum efficiency.

Needless to say, all the complex exponentiation will chew more CPU time and hurt accuracy compared to the purely real algorithm for symmetrical distributions above.

Answer (score 17):

You cau use dynamic programming in order to generate binomial coefficients

You can create an array and than use *O(N^2)* loop to fill it

```
C[n, k] = C[n-1, k-1] + C[n-1, k];
```

where

```
C[1, 1] = C[n, n] = 1
```

After that in your program you can get the C(n, k) value just looking at your 2D array at [n, k] indices

**UPDATE** smth like that

```
for (int k = 1; k <= K; k++) C[0][k] = 0;
for (int n = 0; n <= N; n++) C[n][0] = 1;

for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++)
   for (int k = 1; k <= K; k++)
      C[n][k] = C[n-1][k-1] + C[n-1][k];
```

where the N, K - maximum values of your n, k

Comment: shouldn't N and K be the same value? I don't think there's a point in memoizing a disproportionate Pascal's triangle

Comment: @ScottNguyen code is shown in the most generic form. You can modify N and K to whatever-you-wish

Comment: +1. Good solution. Just to be specific instead of using O(n*2) memory, it can be evaluated using O(N) memory, as according to the problem definition in the question, it is just interested in coefficients of N.

Comment: @Dreamer, yes O(n) memory for the question posed by the OP as you and Scott point out , but still O(n^2) time.

Answer (score 16):

If you need to compute them for all n, Ribtoks's answer is probably the best.
For a single n, you're better off doing like this:

```
C[0] = 1
for (int k = 0; k < n; ++ k)
    C[k+1] = (C[k] * (n-k)) / (k+1)
```

The division is exact, *if* done after the multiplication.

And beware of overflowing with C[k] * (n-k) : use large enough integers.

Answer (score 8):

I recently wrote a piece of code that needed to call for a binary coefficient about 10 million times. So I did a combination lookup-table/calculation approach that's still not too wasteful of memory. You might find it useful (and my code is in the public domain). The code is at

http://www.etceterology.com/fast-binomial-coefficients

It's been suggested that I inline the code here. A big honking lookup table seems like a waste, so here's the final function, and a Python script that generates the table:

```
extern long long bctable[]; /* See below */

long long binomial(int n, int k) {
    int i;
    long long b;
    assert(n >= 0 && k >= 0);

    if (0 == k || n == k) return 1LL;
    if (k > n) return 0LL;

    if (k > (n - k)) k = n - k;
    if (1 == k) return (long long)n;

    if (n <= 54 && k <= 54) {
        return bctable[(((n - 3) * (n - 3)) >> 2) + (k - 2)];
    }
    /* Last resort: actually calculate */
    b = 1LL;
    for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i) {
        b *= (n - (k - i));
        if (b < 0) return -1LL; /* Overflow */
        b /= i;
    }
    return b;
}
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.table = [[0 for k in range(max + 1)] for n in range(max + 1)]
        self.max = max

    def build(self):
        for n in range(self.max + 1):
            for k in range(self.max + 1):
                if k == 0:      b = 1
                elif  k > n:    b = 0
                elif k == n:    b = 1
                elif k == 1:    b = n
                elif k > n-k:   b = self.table[n][n-k]
                else:
                    b = self.table[n-1][k] + self.table[n-1][k-1]
                self.table[n][k] = b

    def output(self, val):
        if val > 2**63: val = -1
        text = " {0}LL,".format(val)

        if self.column + len(text) > 76:
            print("\n   ", end = "")
            self.column = 3
        print(text, end = "")
        self.column += len(text)

    def dump(self):
        count = 0
        print("long long bctable[] = {", end="");

        self.column = 999
        for n in range(self.max + 1):
            for k in range(self.max + 1):
                if n < 4 or k < 2 or k > n-k:
                    continue
                self.output(self.table[n][k])
                count += 1
        print("\n}}; /* {0} Entries */".format(count));

    def run(self):
        self.build()
        self.dump()
        return 0

def main(args):
    return App(54).run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 7):

This is my version:

```
def binomial(n, k):
if k == 0:
    return 1
elif 2*k > n:
    return binomial(n,n-k)
else:
    e = n-k+1
    for i in range(2,k+1):
        e *= (n-k+i)
        e /= i
    return e
```

Answer (score 6):

If you really only need the case where n is much larger than p, one way to go would be to use the [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for the factorials. (if n>>1 and p is order one, Stirling approximate n! and (n-p)!, keep p! as it is etc.)

Comment: Even better, use lgamma and additions to avoid overflows

Answer (score 4):

The fastest reasonable approximation in my own benchmarking is the approximation used by the Apache Commons Maths library: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/special/Gamma.html#logGamma(double)

My colleagues and I tried to see if we could beat it, while using exact calculations rather than approximates.  All approaches failed miserably (many orders slower) except one, which was 2-3 times slower.  The best performing approach uses https://math.stackexchange.com/a/202559/123948, here is the code (in Scala):

```
var i: Int = 0
var binCoeff: Double = 1
while (i < k) {
  binCoeff *= (n - i) / (k - i).toDouble
  i += 1
}
binCoeff
```

The really bad approaches where various attempts at implementing Pascal's Triangle using tail recursion.

Answer (score 2):

```
nCp = n! / ( p! (n-p)! ) =
      ( n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * (n - p) * (n - p - 1) * ... * 1 ) /
      ( p * (p-1) * ... * 1     * (n - p) * (n - p - 1) * ... * 1 )
```

If we prune the same terms of the numerator and the denominator, we are left with minimal multiplication required. We can write a function in C to perform 2p multiplications and 1 division to get nCp:

```
int binom ( int p, int n ) {
    if ( p == 0 ) return 1;
    int num = n;
    int den = p;
    while ( p > 1 ) {
        p--;
        num *= n - p;
        den *= p;
    }
    return num / den;
}
```

Comment: `num` might exceed 32/64 bit even if the result might not. The function is practically safe only with `p <= 12`.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and couldn't find it, so wrote one myself that seems optimal for any Binomial Coeffcient for which the endresult fits into a Long.

```
// Calculate Binomial Coefficient 
// Jeroen B.P. Vuurens
public static long binomialCoefficient(int n, int k) {
    // take the lowest possible k to reduce computing using: n over k = n over (n-k)
    k = java.lang.Math.min( k, n - k );

    // holds the high number: fi. (1000 over 990) holds 991..1000
    long highnumber[] = new long[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        highnumber[i] = n - i; // the high number first order is important
    // holds the dividers: fi. (1000 over 990) holds 2..10
    int dividers[] = new int[k - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
        dividers[i] = k - i;

    // for every dividers there is always exists a highnumber that can be divided by 
    // this, the number of highnumbers being a sequence that equals the number of 
    // dividers. Thus, the only trick needed is to divide in reverse order, so 
    // divide the highest divider first trying it on the highest highnumber first. 
    // That way you do not need to do any tricks with primes.
    for (int divider: dividers) {
       boolean eliminated = false;
       for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
          if (highnumber[i] % divider == 0) {
             highnumber[i] /= divider;
             eliminated = true;
             break;
          }
       }
       if(!eliminated) throw new Error(n+","+k+" divider="+divider);
    }


    // multiply remainder of highnumbers
    long result = 1;
    for (long high : highnumber)
       result *= high;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Quite nice, but that nested for loop designed to avoid floating point arithmetic seems more expensive than just using floating point arithmatic.

Comment: Good point. However, did you try the floating point approach for very big numbers? I wonder if it doesn't lose precision at some point. This method could still compute exact outcomes using BigDecimal instead of longs.

Comment: This algorithm is incorrect. The loop `for (int divider: dividers) ...` is invalid.

Comment: @Atom can you elaborate why that loop is invalid by stating for which input the answer is incorrect? I've just tested it again, it is in maven io.github.htools in lib.MathTools and appears to work for me...

Comment: @JeroenVuurens For some combinations of `n` and `k` the `break` statement is never reached and thus the divider is not eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the notation in the question, you don't just want nCp, you actually want all of nC1, nC2, ... nC(n-1). If this is correct, we can leverage the following relationship to make this fairly trivial:

- for all k>0: nCk = prod_{from i=1..k}( (n-i+1)/i )
- i.e. for all k>0: nCk = nC(k-1) * (n-k+1) / k

Here's a python snippet implementing this approach:

```
def binomial_coef_seq(n, k):
    """Returns a list of all binomial terms from choose(n,0) up to choose(n,k)"""
    b = [1]
    for i in range(1,k+1):
        b.append(b[-1] * (n-i+1)/i)
    return b
```

If you need all coefficients up to some k > ceiling(n/2), you can use symmetry to reduce the number of operations you need to perform by stopping at the coefficient for ceiling(n/2) and then just backfilling as far as you need.

```
import numpy as np

def binomial_coef_seq2(n, k):
    """Returns a list of all binomial terms from choose(n,0) up to choose(n,k)"""

    k2 = int(np.ceiling(n/2))

    use_symmetry =  k > k2
    if use_symmetry:
        k = k2

    b = [1]
    for i in range(1, k+1):
        b.append(b[-1] * (n-i+1)/i)

    if use_symmetry:
        v = k2 - (n-k)
        b2 = b[-v:]
        b.extend(b2)
    return b
```

Answer (score 1):

Time Complexity : O(denominator)
Space Complexity : O(1)

```
public class binomialCoeff {
    static double binomialcoeff(int numerator, int denominator) 
    { 
        double res = 1; 
        //invalid numbers
        if (denominator>numerator || denominator<0 || numerator<0) {
            res = -1;
            return res;}
        //default values
        if(denominator==numerator || denominator==0 || numerator==0)
            return res;


        // Since C(n, k) = C(n, n-k) 
        if ( denominator > (numerator - denominator) ) 
            denominator = numerator - denominator;


        // Calculate value of [n * (n-1) *---* (n-k+1)] / [k * (k-1) *----* 1] 
        while (denominator>=1)
        { 

        res *= numerator;
        res = res / denominator; 

        denominator--;
        numerator--;
        } 

        return res; 
    } 

    /* Driver program to test above function*/
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int numerator = 120; 
        int denominator = 20; 
        System.out.println("Value of C("+ numerator + ", " + denominator+ ") "
                                + "is" + " "+ binomialcoeff(numerator, denominator)); 
    } 

}
```