# Is a memory function (Dynamic Programming) a good approach for computing binomial coefficient?

Tags: dynamic-programming

Recursive function for computing binomial coefficient:

C(n,k) = C(n-1,k-1) + C(n-1,k), n > k > 0 with C(i,0) = C(i,i) = 1, 0 <= i <= n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to generate binomial coefficients](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032781/fastest-way-to-generate-binomial-coefficients)

Comment: And even if it's not a duplicate, the answer is there.